# How to use Boost Serialization with derived classes in C++?

Tags: c++, macos, serialization, gcc, boost

I am trying to use Boost's serialization functionality to serialize a derived class.  My base class doesn't have different data members, so the derived class just has this serialize() function:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Car>(*this);
}
```

Then the base class has this serialize() function:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & color;
    ar & miles;
    ar & model;
    ar & doors;
}
```

Adding this to the base class made no difference:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Car)
```

The program compiles just fine.  The main() generates some dummy data, prints it to stdout, then saves it with boost serialization.  Then it attempts to read the data from the file and print the results.  It saves the data just fine, and I can open the data files and confirm that the data is in fact present.

However, when rebuilding the derived class (and when also rebuilding an instance of the base class), it fails at the beginning of the serialize() function for the base class.  Any thoughts?  I think I did everything correctly from the example provided on the boost website.  Thank you in advance.  Also, I'm using GCC 4 on Mac OS X and the latest boost library (from source), and the sample program works fine with boost when not dealing with inheritance.

**Update:**
I get the same problem when trying to run the sample code in the Boost documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#derivedclasses:

```
class bus_stop_corner: public bus_stop {
friend class boost::serialization::access;
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop_corner &bsc);
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    // serialize base class information
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<bus_stop>(*this); // Fails here
    ar & street1;
    ar & street2;
}
string street1;
string street2;
virtual string description() const {
    return street1 + " and " + street2;
}
public:
bus_stop_corner(){}
bus_stop_corner(const gps_position & lat_, const gps_position & long_, const string & s1_, const string & s2_): bus_stop(lat_, long_), street1(s1_), street2(s2_) {}
};
```

For `ar & boost::serialization::base_object<bus_stop>(*this);` GDB says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

## Derived.h

```
#ifndef BoostSerialization_Derived_h
#define BoostSerialization_Derived_h
// This is pretty much the same code from the Boost Serialization documentation!
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class gps_position {
public:
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s):degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s) {}
    gps_position(const gps_position &gp) {this->degrees = gp.degrees; this->minutes = gp.minutes; this->seconds = gp.seconds;}
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
};

class bus_stop {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop &bsc);
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & latitude;
        ar & longitude;
    }
protected:
    gps_position latitude;
    gps_position longitude;
    bus_stop(const gps_position & lat_, const gps_position & long_): latitude(lat_),   longitude(long_) {}
public:
    bus_stop(){}
    bus_stop(const bus_stop &bs) {this->latitude = bs.latitude; this->longitude = bs.longitude;}
    // See item # 14 in Effective C++ by Scott Meyers.
    // re non-virtual destructors in base classes.
    virtual ~bus_stop(){}
};

class bus_stop_corner: public bus_stop {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop_corner &bsc);
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        // serialize base class information
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<bus_stop>(*this);
        ar & street1;
        ar & street2;
    }
    string street1;
    string street2;
    virtual string description() const {
        return street1 + " and " + street2;
    }
public:
    bus_stop_corner(){}
    bus_stop_corner(const bus_stop_corner &bsc) {this->street1 = bsc.street1; this->street2 = bsc.street2; this->latitude = bsc.latitude; this->longitude = bsc.longitude;}
    bus_stop_corner(const gps_position & lat_, const gps_position & long_, const string & s1_, const string & s2_): bus_stop(lat_, long_), street1(s1_), street2(s2_) {}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const gps_position &gps);
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop &bsc);
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop_corner &bsc);

void derivedClassTest();
void derivedClassSave();
void derivedClassLoad();
#endif
```

## Derived.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"
#include "GenericSerializer.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const gps_position &gps) {
    out << gps.degrees << " degrees " << gps.minutes << "\" " << gps.seconds << "'";
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop &bsc) {
    out << "Bus stop at " << bsc.latitude << " and " << bsc.longitude;
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const bus_stop_corner &bsc) {
    out << "Bus stop at the corner of " << bsc.street1 << " and " << bsc.street2;
    return out;
}

void derivedClassTest() {
    derivedClassSave();
    derivedClassLoad();
}

void derivedClassSave() {
    gps_position lat;
    gps_position lng;

    lat.degrees = 1;
    lat.minutes = 2;
    lat.seconds = 3.3;

    lng.degrees = 4;
    lng.minutes = 5;
    lng.seconds = 6.66;

    bus_stop_corner bsc(lat, lng, "Str. A", "ul. B");

    cout << "Bus stop: " << bsc << endl;

    GenericSerializer<bus_stop_corner> serializer(bsc);
    serializer.save("bus_stop.dat");
}

void derivedClassLoad() {
    GenericSerializer<bus_stop_corner> serializer("bus_stop.dat");
    bus_stop_corner bsc = serializer.getData();

    cout << "Loaded bus stop: " << bsc << endl;
}
```

## GenericSerializer.h

```
#ifndef BoostSerialization_GenericSerializer_h
#define BoostSerialization_GenericSerializer_h

#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class Serializable>
class GenericSerializer {
private:
    Serializable *data;

public:
    GenericSerializer(const Serializable &s);
    ~GenericSerializer();
    void save(string filename);

    GenericSerializer(string filename);
    Serializable getData() const;
    void load(string filename);
};

#include "GenericSerializer.cpp"

#endif
```

## GenericSerializer.cpp

```
//#define BINARY

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#ifdef BINARY
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#endif
#include <string>
#include "GenericSerializer.h"
using namespace std;

template <class Serializable>
GenericSerializer<Serializable>::GenericSerializer(const Serializable &s) {
    this->data = new Serializable(s);
}

template <class Serializable>
GenericSerializer<Serializable>::~GenericSerializer() {
    delete this->data;
}

template <class Serializable>
void GenericSerializer<Serializable>::save(string filename) {
    ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
#ifdef BINARY
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs, boost::archive::no_header);
#else
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
#endif
    oa << *data;
    ofs.close();
}

template <class Serializable>
GenericSerializer<Serializable>::GenericSerializer(string filename) {
    this->load(filename);
}

template <class Serializable>
Serializable GenericSerializer<Serializable>::getData() const {
    return *this->data;
}

template <class Serializable>
void GenericSerializer<Serializable>::load(string filename) {
    ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
#ifdef BINARY
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs, boost::archive::no_header);
#else
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
#endif
    ia >> *data; 
}
```

## Output with GDB

```
Bus stop: Bus stop at the corner of Str. A and ul. B

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffff78fcf04 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff78fcf04 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7ba395f in resize (this=0x7fffffffdc60, s=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h:667
#2  boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::load (this=0x7fffffffdc60, s=...)
    at ./boost/archive/impl/basic_binary_iprimitive.ipp:111
#3  0x000000000040b9d8 in boost::archive::load_access::load_primitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
> (ar=..., t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:107
#4  0x000000000040b73f in boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_primitive::invoke<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (ar=..., t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:356
#5  0x000000000040b4f1 in boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::invoke<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (ar=..., t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:433
#6  0x000000000040b07a in boost::archive::load<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
> (
    ar=..., t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:580
#7  0x000000000040ad68 in boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:68
#8  0x000000000040ab6f in boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=..., version=0) at /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp:67
#9  0x000000000040a921 in boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::load_override<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:50
#10 0x000000000040a6c8 in boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::operator>><std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:61
#11 0x000000000040a445 in boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::operator&<std::string> (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:68
#12 0x000000000040a107 in bus_stop_corner::serialize<boost::archive::binary_iarchive> (this=0x62d958, ar=..., version=0) at Derived.h:62
#13 0x0000000000409c5c in boost::serialization::access::serialize<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., t=..., file_version=0)
    at /usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118
#14 0x000000000040994f in boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., t=..., file_version=0)
    at /usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:74
#15 0x0000000000409544 in boost::serialization::serialize_adl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., t=..., file_version=0)
    at /usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:133
#16 0x0000000000408f12 in boost::archive::detail::iserializer<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, bus_stop_corner>::load_object_data (this=0x62aa30, ar=..., 
    x=0x62d958, file_version=0) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:182
#17 0x00007ffff7b9b857 in load_object (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=<value optimized out>, bis=...) at libs/serialization/src/basic_iarchive.cpp:399
#18 boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::load_object (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=<value optimized out>, bis=...)
    at libs/serialization/src/basic_iarchive.cpp:547
#19 0x000000000040838a in boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_standard::invoke<bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., 
    t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:381
#20 0x0000000000408344 in boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::invoke<bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., t=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:433
#21 0x00000000004082dc in boost::archive::load<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, bus_stop_corner> (ar=..., t=...)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:580
#22 0x0000000000408288 in boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override<bus_stop_corner> (this=0x7fffffffdc50, 
    t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:68
#23 0x0000000000408233 in boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override<bus_stop_corner> (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=..., 
    version=0) at /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp:67
#24 0x00000000004081d7 in boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::load_override<bus_stop_corner>
    (this=0x7fffffffdc50, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:50
#25 0x0000000000408150 in boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::operator>><bus_stop_corner> (this=0x7fffffffdc50, 
    t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:61
#26 0x0000000000407ff0 in GenericSerializer<bus_stop_corner>::load (this=0x7fffffffdf40, filename=...) at GenericSerializer.cpp:64
#27 0x0000000000407cff in GenericSerializer<bus_stop_corner>::GenericSerializer (this=0x7fffffffdf40, filename=...) at GenericSerializer.cpp:48
#28 0x00000000004063f1 in derivedClassLoad () at Derived.cpp:53
#29 0x00000000004060f9 in derivedClassTest () at Derived.cpp:29
#30 0x000000000040fcf7 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8) at main.cpp:44
```

## bus_stop.dat (serialization output file)

```
22 serialization::archive 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3.3 4 5 6.6599998 6 Str. A 5 ul. B
```

## gcc -v -H

### On Mac OS X

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
```

### On Ubuntu

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

Comment: If possible, show the source code of your program in its entirety, and all the error messages you are getting, verbatim. "It fails" is not a particularly useful error description. "It gets a SIGSEGV at line 117" would be a little bit more informative.

Comment: It fails when calling the serialization function for the base class, and GDB says the variable points to NULL.

Comment: This is very strange, it's supposed to work. Perhaps you are linking with a wrong version of boost libraries? Run gcc with `-v` and `-H` flags and make sure your includes and libs belong to the same boost version.

Comment: Are you serializing the object directly or through the base? (*Note*: I wouldn't need to ask, if you'd provided a full example.)

Comment: I am serializing the derived class directly, which then calls the base class' serialization function.

Comment: 1. Are you getting the same error on ubuntu? 2. where's your main.cpp? 3. "-H" prints include file paths as they are used so you need to use it as you actually compile your program. Also try to compile and run [this](http://pastebin.com/07A5gmsD) and tell if you are getting an error.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) It's become messy and refers to classes in many other files that would be too much to put online.  I did compile and run your code without any errors.  But what is with those extra braces in the main()?  When I remove them, it still compiles but has a runtime error. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc

Answer (score 0):

The boost demo http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp worked for me. Can you test your code with valgrind to be sure there are no memory error before the incriminated point?

Answer (score -1):

I remember a while ago that my boss had problems with boost serialization on his mac as well. The issue was with using standard iostreams. When we changed the code to use boost iostreams it was working on his mac.

We haven't gotten around digging into this any deeper, so at the moment I can only suggest you to try the same and see if it works:

```
boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::file_sink> ofs( "filename" );
```

P.S. I can not add comments yet to questions, and we can not PM users on SO... so I wrote it as an answer.

Edit: Ok I see you also tested on Ubuntu.. I should read more carefully. Still, it might be worth trying this, if it does not work I will delete this answer.

Comment: This did not work for me